# Multiple Macros in C

Tags: c

```
#define a 10
#define a 20
{

    printf("%d",a);
}
```

Why is the answer 20 and not 10?
Since /* #define a 10 */ is the first macro, isn't that supposed to get substitued in place of 'a'?

Comment: Since `#define a 20` is the second macro, isn't that supposed to get substituted in place of `a`?

Comment: the `gcc` compiler issues a `warning: "a" redefined` when the second definition is different from the first one(s) but overrides it without problems.

Comment: If your question is about C, why did you make a decision to use the [tag:c++] tag?

Comment: But when a searches for a substituion, it finds out that #define a 10 was declared first. So shouldn't a be replaced by 10?

Comment: `a` doesn't search for anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The premise of your question (that the first definition should be used) is wrong.

Your compiler has decided to use the second definition. It could really do whatever it likes, since your program is ill-formed/broken/wrong:

> `[C99: 6.10.3/2]:` An identifier currently defined as an object-like macro shall not be redefined by another `#define` preprocessing directive unless the second definition is an object-like macro definition and the two replacement lists are identical. *[..]*

Here, in [the documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Undefining-and-Redefining-Macros.html), we see GCC's non-standard behaviour clearly defined:

> **If a macro is redefined with a definition that is not effectively the same as the old one, the preprocessor issues a warning and changes the macro to use the new definition.** If the new definition is effectively the same, the redefinition is silently ignored. This allows, for instance, two different headers to define a common macro. The preprocessor will only complain if the definitions do not match.

In short: **don't do this.**

Comment: I do admit that the code in ill-formed, I just wanted to know how the flow of the code would be in such a situation. Anyway, Thank You! :)

Comment: @AbhijitIyer: You should do yourself a favour and get into the habit of studying/reading/using _documentation_ instead of just trusting hearsay :)